# auto increment value in django

Tags: python, django, loops, error-handling

i have an table in django and try to auto increment it's serial no. in custom template for loop is used for the variables.

custom template

```
{% for i in getodeskview %}
    <tr>
        <td> 1. </td>
        <td>{{ i.odesk_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.hours }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.feedback }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="/odesk/?editodeskform={{i.id}} " title="Edit"><i class="splashy-document_letter_edit"></i></a>
            <!---- <a href="/hours/?addhid={{i.app_id}}" title="Interview"><i class="splashy-document_letter_okay"></i></a>----->
            <a href="/deleteodesk/?dltodid={{i.id}}" title="Remove"><i class="splashy-document_letter_remove"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

how to increment the values.

Comment: you can store value you need to increment in model or cache and increment it with every request so far...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `{{ forloop.counter }}` inside loop to get the index.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Answer (score 1):

Use [forloop_counter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for). This keeps track of the number of times the loop has run so far.

Answer (score 1):

Use `{{ forloop.counter }}`.

Source:
[Built-in template tags and filters #for](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

I hope it will solve you problem