# How to add auto number column in the tables?

Tags: python, django, templates

I am learning Django and my first project I am doing a To do application. My idea is that I put the content from the database(models.py) into tables in html ,but also on the side of the table I wanna put a auto number column that which is added in the number of items in table. I tried to do that function with count() function in views.py, but the problem is that when i add a new item in the table the number item column is the same in the number in first row, and second, etc...
[This is a screenshot of the page to understand it easily](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nilWi.png)

This is views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import Count

from .models import *
from .models import __str__
# Create your views here.


def home(request):
    count_item = todo.objects.count()
    all_items = todo.objects.all().order_by("created")
    context = {'all_items': all_items, 'count_item':count_item}

    return render(request, 'html/home.html', context)


def add_todo(request):
    current_date = timezone.now()
    new_item= todo(content = request.POST["content"])
    new_item.save()
    return redirect('/')


def delete_todo(request, todo_id):
    item_to_delete = todo.objects.get(id=todo_id)
    item_to_delete.delete()
    return redirect('/')
```

This is home.html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div style="background-color: #0d2e72;" class="card">
      <div class="card-header" style="border: none;">
        <p style="font-size: 25px; text-align: center; color: white;">TASKS TO DO</p>       
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table table-dark table-hover table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr id="tr-table">
              <th id="text-left" style="">ADD ITEMS</th>
              <th id="text-center">ITEMS</th>
              <th id="text-right">ACTIONS</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>  
          <tbody>
            {% for all_item in all_items %}
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{count_item}}</th>
                <td>{{ all_item.content }}</td>
                <form action="delete_todo/{{all_item.id}}/" method="post">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <td class="text-right">
                    <button id="btn-delete" class="btn btn-outline-danger" style="width: 80px;">Delete</button> 
                  </td>
                </form>
             </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class todo(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

I hope you guys would suggest me a solution about this problem. I would appreciate any response.

Comment: Please check this - > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847081/auto-increment-value-in-django

Comment: Why don't you show the 'id' as your auto_number?

Comment: @Learner thank you. The problem is solved